# How to delete a python object or how to create a new object with the same name (overwritting the old)?

Tags: python

I want to delete or overwrite a python object.

First, here is simple class.

```
>>> def Myclass():
...    def __init__(self, name, value=[]):
...        self.name = name
...        self.value = value
...
```

Then I create an object of `Myclass` and add something to the `value` attribute.

```
>>> m1 = Myclass('m1')
>>> m1.value.append('a')
>>> m1.value.append('b')
>>> m1.value
['a', 'b']
```

Now I try to delete it.

```
>>> del m1
>>> m1.value  ### the variable seem to be properly erased
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'm1' is not defined
```

Seems to be properly deleted. I try to create a new object with the same name (because I want to overwrite the old values).

```
>>> m1 = Myclass('m1')
>>> m1.value
['a', 'b'] ### The previous value was not erased!!
```

It seems the `del` command on python is not actually deleting the variable. Do I need to manually call the garbage collector to erase it?

I'm using python 3.6.3

Comment: Your problem is nothing to do with `del`. This: `def __init__(self, name, value=[])` is called a "mutable default argument", and it is nearly always not what you want.

Comment: You are deleting...and then trying to access?